# Prepare shell script for output to file and console

Tags: bash, shell, output

I know that there is a possibility to use `tee` to copy the contents of output to a file and still output it to the console.

However, I can't seem to find a way, to prepare shell scripts (like a fixed template) without using `tee` for either each command in the script or to execute the script using a pipe to `tee`.

Thus, I have to start calling the script each time with a pipe to `tee` instead of automatically doing this for me via the script.

I tried using a modified shebang using a pipe but got no success and I can't seem to find a way to accomplish this.

So instead of calling the script like this:

```
./myscript.sh |& tee scriptout.txt
```

I would like to have the same effect just by calling it like this:

```
./myscript
```

Of course the script needs to know the filename which is set in a variable inside the script.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could wrap the contents of your script in a function and pipe the functions output to `tee`:

```
#!/bin/bash

{
echo "example script"
} | tee -a /logfile.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

You can probably do something like setting the output at the start of the script using `exec`. (I haven't tested this very strongly.)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Split script output to stdout and to the logfile
exec 1> >(tee -a "/tmp/${0##*/}.log")

# Write a message
echo hello, world

# Empirical pause before exiting to wait for all output to get through the tee
sleep 1
exit 0
```

Example, assuming the script is called `demo` and has been made executable with `chmod a+x demo`:

```
ls -l /tmp/demo.log
ls: cannot access '/tmp/demo.log': No such file or directory

./demo
hello, world

cat /tmp/demo.log
hello, world
```